# Imagick's 'thumbnailImage' function doesn't work

Tags: php, imagick

I use the Imagick's function `thumbnailImage` to resize my PNG image.

It doesn't change the size on my website, but with the function `getImageGeometry` the new dimension has been applied. I've also used the function `resizeImage` but nothing changes.

My script (running on Windows):

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->readImage('page.png');
$im->thumbnailImage(1024, 768, TRUE);

echo "<img src='page.png'>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resized image data is in Imagick object, you may save it back, or output the content directly.

```
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($imagick->getImageBlob())."'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it better, in case other [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) is used:

```
printf(
    '<img src="data:%s;base64,%s">',
    $imagick->getImageMimeType(),
    base64_encode($imagick->getImageBlob())
);
```